# Shiny app filling output that depends on input does not work

Tags: r, shiny, shiny-server

I'm working on a some text mining. Based on the user's input I'm generating a number of suggestions for the next word. This part works fine. However the number of suggestions can be very large, so I want to show at most 10 suggestions in Shiny and I don't want to show NA values.

I created a reproducable example to exhibits the same problem. The trick I'm trying to use is pasting "suggestions" with i. This works when my output does not depend on my input. I got this from http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/creating-a-ui-from-a-loop.html.

My ui.R file

```
    library(shiny)

    fluidPage(
            titlePanel("Test"),
            fluidRow(
                    textAreaInput("userText", label="Enter your text")
            ),
            fluidRow(
                    lapply(1:5, function(i) {
                            textOutput(paste0("suggestions", i))})
            )
    )
```

My server.R

```
    library(shiny)

    mySuggestions <- c("this", "is", "a", "test", "of", "getting", "reactive", "list", "length")

    function(input, output, session) {

            getWords <- function(i, wrds) {
                    output[[paste0("suggestions", i)]] <- renderText({ wrds()[i] })
            }

            userText <- reactive({ 
                    # Leaves this function when input$userText is NULL or ""
                    req(input$userText)
                    input$userText })

            words <- reactive({
                    mySuggestions[1:userText()]
            })
            # Problem
            lapply(reactive({ 1:min(5,  length(words())) }), getWords(), wrds=words()) 
    }
```

When you enter a positive integer in the ui text field the app is supposed to show as many words, but 5 at most.

The above version of the server.R results in a warning "Warning: Error in paste0: argument "i" is missing, with no default"
I've tried several versions for this problematic line.

```
    reactive({ lapply(1:min(5,  length(words())), getWords(), wrds=words() ) })
```

Gives no errors, but it shows nothing in the output.

```
    lapply(1:min(5,  length(words())), getWords() , wrds=words())
```

Results in a warning "Warning: Error in paste0: argument "i" is missing, with no default"

```
    lapply(reactive({1:min(5,  length(words()))}), getWords(), wrds=words())
```

Results in a warning "Warning: Error in paste0: argument "i" is missing, with no default"

```
     lapply(reactive({1:min(5,  length(words))}), function(i) {
              output[[paste0("suggestions", i)]] <- renderText({ words[i] }) } )
```

Results in Error in as.vector(x, "list") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'

```
     lapply(reactive({1:min(5,  length(words()))}), function(i) {
              output[[paste0("suggestions", i)]] <- renderText({ words()[i] }) } )
```

Results in Error in as.vector(x, "list") : 
  cannot coerce type 'closure' to vector of type 'list'

```
     reactive({lapply(1:min(5,  length(words)), function(i) {
              output[[paste0("suggestions", i)]] <- renderText({ words[i] }) }) })
```

Gives no errors, but it shows nothing in the output.

```
     reactive({lapply(1:min(5,  length(words())), function(i) {
              output[[paste0("suggestions", i)]] <- renderText({ words()[i] }) }) })
```

Gives no errors, but it shows nothing in the output.

```
     lapply(1:min(5,  reactive({ length(words )})), function(i) {
             output[[paste0("suggestions", i)]] <- renderText({ words[i] }) })
```

Results in Error in min(5, reactive({ : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

```
     lapply(1:min(5,  reactive({ length(words() )})), function(i) {
             output[[paste0("suggestions", i)]] <- renderText({ words()[i] }) })
```

Results in Error in min(5, reactive({ : invalid 'type' (closure) of argument

Now the following line shows the entered number of words in a single text field. When I enter 2 it shows 2 words and when I enter 20 it shows 5 words. This is the behaviour I want, but I want each word in a separate text field.

```
    output$suggestions1 <- renderText(words()[1:min(5, length(words()))])
```

I'm getting lost. I was getting so desperate that I tried a few things I did not expect to work. 
Is it possible to do what I want? If so, how? If not, what is the problem? I haven't found anything yet that addresses this specific problem.

Comment: Looks fun but I don't have time now to tackle it. Maybe later tonight.

Comment: Try coding it simply, without any lapplys and then consolidate. And also  look at the Shiny Cheat sheet #3. Execution Model to make sure your mental model of Shiny execution is correct. I think it may not be.

Comment: @MikeWise. I also tried it with for loops. Didn't work either. I think it has to do with mixing the scope of the `render` and `reactive` statements. I think the way I tried it before required mixing these scopes and that is probably not allowed. Using `observe` works. Apparently that's somehow a mixed scope.

Comment: You know that external lapply only ever executes once, right?

Comment: Ah, I get what you mean. Thanks for the cheat sheet reference, very helpful in developing my mental picture. The external lapply attempts where more or less out of desperation. The once enclose by a `reactive` statement didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of outputUI and renderUI works great and keeps the code relatively simple.

ui.R

```
    ...
    fluidRow(
            uiOutput("suggestions")
    )
```

server.R

```
    library(shiny)

    mySuggestions <- c("this", "is", "a", "test", "of", "getting", "reactive", "list", "length")

    function(input, output, session) {

            ...

            output$suggestions <- renderUI({ 
                    lapply(1:min(5, length(words())), function(i) {
                    output[[paste0("suggestions", i)]] <- renderText({ words()[i] })
            }) })
    }
```

I didn't know what outputUI and renderUI did, but they seem perfect for situations like these.

Comment: But will it work if you change the value of userText up and down a few times? Not convinced you won't get some unwanted definitions hanging around.

Comment: Also a great lecture on Shiny design patterns from the main architect of Shiny:https://www.rstudio.com/resources/webinars/shiny-developer-conference/

Comment: @MikeWise. You're right. Going up is no problem, but if I enter a smaller number it doesn't work anymore. Back to the drawing board :(